# How can I monitor a Facebook app that requires login from a remote service

Tags: facebook, monitoring

I have a Facebook application that runs within an iframe. If I call the source URL itself, it will always require FB authentication. Within the context of the FB page this is not a problem, as users will always be logged in, however, this does prevent remote monitoring services from 'seeing' the app. I would like to use Pingdom to monitor the app source - is this possible, and if so, how?

[Edit: the requirement for FB authentication is a fixed client requirement - so please don't suggest I simply remove it - I can't. My question is whether there are any remote monitoring servives, like Pingdom, that allow me to pre-auth the app so that it can be monitored.]

Comment: I'm looking into the same problem and think that one way to go about it to leave a single URL outside of the facebook authentication loop so that it can be easily pinged from the outside

Answer (score -2):

It is not accurate to state that all Facebook apps run in iframes.  There are native client apps that do not run in a browser, and Connect applications that run outside of the Facebook chrome.

Just make a page that does not require Facebook authentication.

Comment: The question above refers to a real app that exists already. It can't be changed.

Comment: The pages that are loaded in an iframe are yours.  You control whether they require Facebook authentication.  You can have a canvas app page that is in an iframe and does not require Facebook authentication.  There is no requirement to have any Facebook code or elements on your canvas page.

Comment: I know that the pages are mine. I also know that I could remove FB authentication. Unfortunately I also know that my client would fire me if I did, since that is an explicitly requirement. My question may be ambiguous (will edit), so just to be clear - I cannot change the requirements, or the app - I just want to know whether there are any remote monitors that will allow me to incorporate FB authentication.